# support media compact 25.4.0 file not found error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library

One of my old project I am getting following error.
as 25.4.0 jar file not present how to solve this without upgradition of project compile, build tool version as other developers also working on this project.

```
Could not find support-media-compat.jar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.4.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/25.4.0/support-media-compat-25.4.0.jar
```

Only for my Android studio I am getting this issue for other team mates there project is working fine

here is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven"
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.m.p"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    buildTypes {
        /*release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }*/
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'gson'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile project(':commons')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.lsjwzh.RecyclerViewPager:lib:v1.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'
    compile 'com.github.jrvansuita:CheckNewAppVersionAvailable:v1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
//    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
//    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'

}
```

and here is my common library which include inside project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

Comment: you didn't add the `google()` script your buildscript repositories.

Comment: I just running with same code which othere developers have on there machines, I  am only who getting this issue

Comment: for that reason I'm telling you the config in this machine is different you need to add the`google()` cuz the gradle plugging must be different

Answer (score 0):

You messed up your build.gradle(project), I recommend you revert it back to its or default form.
You usually make changes on build.gradle(module) and let it sync.
I found some lines of code that shouldn't belong on the build.gradle(project).

build.gradle(Project) should look like this.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Module) should look like this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.barcodescanner"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

compile is replace by implementation

Answer (score 0):

inside the `build.gradle` of project, label add

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
       jcenter()
    }
}
```

And update your dependency to the latest version as google play store is not allowing to upload the app which is targeting the SDK version less then oreo (8.0+).
Replace compile to implementation.